# Getting pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException while running sql query in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am running SQL query on pyspark and getting below error.

Can you please help me?

```
query = "select DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PROD_NM, CNTRY) AS SYSTEM_ID,  id AS SOURCE_ID,source_name,prod_nm,CNTRY,source_entity,entity_name from(SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME,prod_nm, 'PROD2' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME,CASE WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS = 'Janssen Canada' THEN 'Canada' WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS LIKE 'Janssen US%' THEN 'United States' END AS CNTRY FROM vw_prod2  UNION SELECT mdm_id , 'MDM' AS SOURCE_NAME, product_name AS PROD_NM, 'MDM_PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME FROM vm_mdm_product PROD, vm_mdm_countries  WHERE PROD.COUNTRY_ID = vm_mdm_countries.COUNTRY_ID UNION SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME, nm AS PROD_NM, 'PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, CNTRY FROM vw_prod union select DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PROD_NM, CNTRY) AS SYSTEM_ID,  id AS SOURCE_ID,source_name,prod_nm,CNTRY,source_entity,entity_name from(SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME,prod_nm, 'PROD2' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME,CASE WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS = 'Janssen Canada' THEN 'Canada' WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS LIKE 'Janssen US%' THEN 'United States' END AS CNTRY FROM vw_prod2  UNION SELECT mdm_id , 'MDM' AS SOURCE_NAME, product_name AS PROD_NM, 'MDM_PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME FROM vm_mdm_product PROD, vm_mdm_countries  WHERE PROD.COUNTRY_ID = vm_mdm_countries.COUNTRY_ID UNION SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME, nm AS PROD_NM, 'PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, CNTRY FROM vw_prod union select DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PROD_NM, CNTRY) AS SYSTEM_ID,  id AS SOURCE_ID,source_name,prod_nm,CNTRY,source_entity,entity_name from(SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME,prod_nm, 'PROD2' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME,CASE WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS = 'Janssen Canada' THEN 'Canada' WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS LIKE 'Janssen US%' THEN 'United States' END AS CNTRY FROM vw_prod2  UNION SELECT mdm_id , 'MDM' AS SOURCE_NAME, product_name AS PROD_NM, 'MDM_PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME FROM vm_mdm_product PROD, vm_mdm_countries  WHERE PROD.COUNTRY_ID = vm_mdm_countries.COUNTRY_ID UNION SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME, nm AS PROD_NM, 'PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, CNTRY FROM vw_prod union select DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PROD_NM, CNTRY) AS SYSTEM_ID,  id AS SOURCE_ID,source_name,prod_nm,CNTRY,source_entity,entity_name from(SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME,prod_nm, 'PROD2' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME,CASE WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS = 'Janssen Canada' THEN 'Canada' WHEN OPRTNG_CMPNYS LIKE 'Janssen US%' THEN 'United States' END AS CNTRY FROM vw_prod2  UNION SELECT mdm_id , 'MDM' AS SOURCE_NAME, product_name AS PROD_NM, 'MDM_PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME FROM vm_mdm_product PROD, vm_mdm_countries  WHERE PROD.COUNTRY_ID = vm_mdm_countries.COUNTRY_ID UNION SELECT distinct id, 'AMPIL' as SOURCE_NAME, nm AS PROD_NM, 'PROD' AS Source_Entity,'PRODUCT' AS ENTITY_NAME, CNTRY FROM vw_prod"

df = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 353, in sql
    return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 710, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
    raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 133)
```

Comment: Please reformat the query you're posting here. There's lots of (online) tools that can do this for you. After reformatting, I can see the following issues:
1. You don't almost any closing parentheses `)`
2. You keep calling the same tables and views repeatedly in subqueries. Spark isn't great with subqueries, so perhaps think about flattening your code. 
3. You keep nesting and distincting and windowing the same (or similar) pieces of code. While Tungsten is great at optimising your Spark code, try and think about why you need to `distinct` and `window` so many times.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few closing parentheses ")" in your query, please take a look on that.